# Conversão de data

Tags: javascript, node.js, data

Tenho uma data neste formato

```
"2017-10-13T18:15:41.143Z"
```

E gostaria de uma data neste formato

```
10/06/2017 01:42:34 PM (-0300)
```

Como posso fazer a conversão?

Comment: Talvez timezone @vnbrs

Comment: (-0300) seria a diferença de horário em comparação com a hora do GMT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Criei uma função de formatação, basicamente desmembrei a data e fui concatenando aos poucos.

Concateno zero a esquerda em alguns momentos para garantir que fique com 2 dígitos.

Nas horas eu faço um cálculo e verifico se é maior ou igual a 12 para indicar se é PM ou AM.

Utilizo a função [getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) que retorna a diferença, em minutos do fuso horário.

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var dia       = ("00" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
  var mes       = date.getMonth()+1;
  var ano       = date.getFullYear();
  var minutos   = ("00" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
  var segundos  = ("00" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
  var timezone  = date.getTimezoneOffset();
  var horas     = date.getHours() % 12 ? date.getHours() % 12 : 12;
  
  horas = ("00" + horas).slice(-2);
  var txtHoras = horas >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  
  var retorno;
  retorno = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano + ' ';
  retorno = retorno + horas + ':' + minutos + ':' + segundos;
  retorno = retorno + ' ' + txtHoras + ' (' + timezone + ')';
  return  retorno;
}

console.log(new Date()); 
console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
```